# How to assess the "reliability" of standard errors?

Tags: regression, least-squares, standard-deviation, regression-coefficients, standard-error

I am studying linear regression and in particular, I am trying to solve an exercise from my book. The model I am focusing on is about wages and education and the text gives me the output of the estimated model. I have the coefficients, their std. error, their t-ratio and p-value. about the model in general I have $R^2$, S.E. of regression, S.D. of the dependent variable etc.

The question that makes me a bit perplexed is "are the standard errors reliable? why or why not?" but what does it mean for a standard error to be reliable? I was thinking that maybe I should consider t-ratios, because as std. errors increase, the t-ratios decrease.

Thank you all!

(Note that I don't have the dataset, as it is only a theoretical exercise)
[image]

Comment: The t-ratio is simply the coefficient divided by the standard error. It does not tell us anything about the reliability of the standard error. The standard errors tell us how reliably the coefficient was estimated. To say something about the reliability of the standard error, you would need a standard error of this standard error. I don't think enough information has been provided to evaluate the reliability of the standard error.

Comment: "Reliable" could mean that you are intended to look for any evidence that the assumptions needed to justify the estimates of the standard errors might be violated.  For instance, heteroscedastic residuals would suggest the standard errors are incorrect or, at least, need to investigated more closely.  However, that has automatically been tested, so if you trust White's test, you won't worry about that possibility.  What other assumptions are needed to justify a standard error calculation and what evidence does this output supply about the plausibility of those assumptions?

Comment: i just have what i posted above. i think that from the White’s test for heteroskedasticity we can affirm that we must accept the null hypotheses of heteroskedasticity not being present. If this is the case, it means that the variances of the error terms is constant along the regression line. so we can to confirm that the standard errors are reliable. Also, as the t-ratio associated to the regressor educ is high, indicating that the standard error is low, thus we can rely on this standard error. @whuber